# Mapping of code numbers with specific words in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a code numbers and data like this(in Data frame):

```
32      A
33      B
34      C
35      D
36      E 
60      F
```

and I have data like this(in pandas series(that's string)):

```
60
32
32
32
32,33
35
34,35,36
```

Now I want output like this(in data frame):

```
60         F
32         A
32         A
32         A
32,33      A,B
35         D
34,35,36   C,D,E
```

How can I do it in a python ?
Please help me

Comment: Sorry, secoun input is like `L` in my answer? Or something else?

Comment: @ jezrael can you solve this question again with data in the pandas series , I edit the question . please help me .

Comment: I think solution is very similar, only need convert string Series to list by `L=s.str.split(',').tolist()`.

Comment: Another solution is use replace like `df=s.to_frame(name='a')`, then `df['b']=df['a'].replace(d,regex=True)`. I am only on phone, so untested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need replace values in `list` by values of `dict` use double nested `list comprehension`.

For `dict` need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from first column (if necessary) and then select column by `[]` like `['b']`.

```
print (L)
[[60], [32], [32], [32], [32, 33], [35], [34, 35, 36]]

d = df1.set_index('a')['b'].to_dict()
print (d)
{32: 'A', 33: 'B', 34: 'C', 35: 'D', 36: 'E', 60: 'F'}

L1 = [[d[y] for y in x] for x in L]
print (L1)
[['F'], ['A'], ['A'], ['A'], ['A', 'B'], ['D'], ['C', 'D', 'E']]

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':L, 'b':L1})
print (df)
              a          b
0          [60]        [F]
1          [32]        [A]
2          [32]        [A]
3          [32]        [A]
4      [32, 33]     [A, B]
5          [35]        [D]
6  [34, 35, 36]  [C, D, E]
```

If need strings add `join`:

```
L1 = [','.join([d[y] for y in x]) for x in L]
print (L1)
['F', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A,B', 'D', 'C,D,E']

df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[','.join(x) for x in L], 'b':L1})
print (df)
          a      b
0        60      F
1        32      A
2        32      A
3        32      A
4     32,33    A,B
5        35      D
6  34,35,36  C,D,E
```

EDIT:

If `L` is `list` of `string`s:

```
print (L)
['60', '32', '32', '32', '32,33', '35', '34,35,36']

df1['a'] = df1['a'].astype(str)
d = df1.set_index('a')['b'].to_dict()
print (d)
{'32': 'A', '60': 'F', '33': 'B', '35': 'D', '34': 'C', '36': 'E'}

L = [[d[y] for y in x.split(',')] for x in L]
print (L)
[['F'], ['A'], ['A'], ['A'], ['A', 'B'], ['D'], ['C', 'D', 'E']]
```

Comment: L1 = [[d[y] for y in x] for x in L] it give error at this line "Invalid syntax"

Comment: What is `print (L[:10])` ?

Comment: No L is not list of strings

Comment: I dont understand, try check what is difference between your real data and my `d` and `L` ?

Comment: Neat. You could do `df['b'] = df['a'].apply(lambda x: [d[y] for y in x])` as well.

Comment: @JohnGalt - thanks. But I am not 100% sure what are real data of OP, so hard answering.

Comment: @ jezrael on new data it gives me this error , 
KeyError: '['

Comment: Keyerror obviously means something missing. In pandas obviusly if want select column `[`, but not exist. In python I think if want select some key in dict which does not exist. The best is check what are all column names by `print (df.columns.tolist())` or in python `print (list(d.keys()))`. In my opinion this debugging is time consuming, but I have no other idea how find problem. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.
Make a list:

```
list = [[60], [32], [32], [32], [32, 33], [35], [34, 35, 36]]
```

Use a dictionary:

```
dictionary = {60:"F", 32:"A", 33:"B", 34:"C", 35:"D", 36:"E"}
```

Then:

```
for element in list:
    string = ""
    for element2 in element:
        string += element2
        string += ","
    string = string[:-1]
    string += "   "
    for element2 in element:
        string += dictionary[element2]
        string += ","
    string = string[:-1]
    print(string)
```